# Find and replace strings in HTML

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

From this HTML code:

```
<p class="description" dir="ltr">Name is a fine man. <br></p>
```

I'm looking for replacing "Name" using the following code:

```
target = soup.find_all(text="Name")
for v in target:
    v.replace_with('Id')
```

The output I would like to have is:

```
<p class="description" dir="ltr">Id is a fine man. <br></p>
```

When I:

```
print target
[]
```

Why doesn't it find the "Name"?

Thanks!

Comment: try using `str.replace()`, Are you sure you have some text that matches it?

Comment: You have no Element with Text `Name`. Show your HTML, and what you intend to do.

Comment: Not really that clear what you're asking. Firstly did your `soup` find any `text='Name'`? Also is there any code in between `replace_with` and `print target`?

Comment: @Daniel, I edited the question including the HTML.

Comment: @PaulRooney, apparently my `soup` did not find `text='Name'` and there is no code in between,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The text node in your HTML contains some other text besides `"Name"`. In this case, you need to relax search criteria to use *contains* instead of *exact match*, for example, by using regex. Then you can replace matched text nodes with the original text except for `"Name"` part should be replaced with `"Id"` by using simple `string.replace()` method, for example :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """<p class="description" dir="ltr">Name is a fine man. <br></p>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
target = soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r'Name'))
for v in target:
    v.replace_with(v.replace('Name','Id'))
print soup
```

output :

```
<html><body><p class="description" dir="ltr">Id is a fine man. <br/></p></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It returns an empty list because searching for text like this must match the whole text in a tag, so use regular expression instead.

From the official docs: [BeautifulSoup - Search text](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Searching%20by%20CSS%20class)

> text is an argument that lets you search for NavigableString objects
>   instead of Tags. Its value can be a string, a regular expression, a
>   list or dictionary, True or None, or a callable that takes a
>   NavigableString object as its argument:

```
soup.findAll(text="one")
# [u'one']
soup.findAll(t ext=re.compile("paragraph"))
# [u'This is paragraph ', u'This is paragraph ']
soup.findAll(text=lambda(x): len(x) < 12)
# [u'Page title', u'one', u'.', u'two', u'.']
```

P.S.: Already already discussed answers are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936030/using-beautifulsoup-to-search-html-for-string) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054574/python-beautiful-soup-find-text-not-working).